# Docker use MongoDB instance installed on host machine

Tags: docker, mongodb

- I have a virtual machine.
- I have **4 Docker images** (with *quay.io/pterodactyl/core:java*) loaded.
- I have **MongoDB**, installed on host machine, not in Docker.

I want Docker images use **MongoDB**.

My **MongoDB** configuration is :

```
bind_ip = [127.0.0.1, 172.18.0.1]
port = 27017
```

But, it doesn't works. I don't know why.

Comment: similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container/40642961

Comment: and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056522/access-host-database-from-a-docker-container